# Extend the SL4A Android object with a custom stop method

Tags: android, sl4a

I'm running Python on Android using SL4A. I have a script to calculate an average that looks like this:

```
import android
droid = android.Android()
var1 = 10
var2 = 20
var3 = 30
average = float((var1+var2+var3)/3)
droid.makeToast('Average:'+str(average))
f=open('/data/data/com.example.devicecommunication/files/result.txt','w')
f.write(str(average))
f.close()
```

My requirement is to add a method to `droid` named `stop`, so I can define my own logic there.
Is this possible?

Comment: What lnaguage are you using? This looks like Python, correct?

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu I want to add it to the Android class in SL4A and then access using droid.stop() (not as a separate method in the script). Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 1):

You can define classes and methods with Python in sl4a, like this:

```
class MyDroid():
  def stop(self):
    return "I stopped"
```

Is this what you're looking for?

You have a LOT of examples (Tutorials, API reference, overview) on the Wiki page of SL4A : [HERE](https://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/wiki/TableOfContents?tm=6).

You can define a global variable, which you use to run your program in a loop, and when the condition is not met anymore, you call `stop` which takes you out of the loop and ends the program.

Something like will work:

```
runScript = True

def stop():
  global runSCript
  runScript = False

while runScript:
  --do actions
  if --condition-- :
    stop()
```

I don't think this is best practice for Python, but it works..

Comment: You can do a `do while` loop and when calling `stop`, the condition in the while is no longer true and so the program jumps out of the while and ends.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind anything you like to the `droid` object...

```
droid.stop = lambda: 1
print(droid.stop()) # prints 1
```

It's not clear what you'd like to do though. The script you posted has no obvious use for a `stop` method. You can do something like the following, but I'm not sure why you would:

```
def stop():
    import sys
    sys.exit()

droid.stop = stop
```

You need to explain the problem you're trying to solve in more detail.